# What do you call the <database>.<table> syntax in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, select, syntax, terminology

In many databases, when writing a `SELECT` query, you can provide the database name along with the table name in order to resolve any ambiguity the database might encounter in case there are multiple databases with the same table names.

For example, let's say the user currently logged into SQL Server has `SELECT` privileges on databases `DB1` and `DB2`, and BOTH databases have a table named `CUSTOMERS`. The following query would return an error stating that the table name is too ambiguous:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
```

The solution is to be more specific so the database knows which table to query from:

```
SELCT * FROM DB1.CUSTOMERS
```

My question is, what is the name for the `<database>.<table>` syntax in SQL? I'm asking so that my terminology is correct when explaining it to junior devs.

Comment: I usually call this the qualified name. Postgres documentation agrees https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are typically called "qualified" and names, and they can be used when an "unqualified" name is ambiguous, for example when a `select` query pulls data from multiple tables that share column names.